# C++ - stl_alloc.h missing on GCC4.4.4 on Fedora 12?

Tags: c++, gcc, fedora, bsd

I am in the process of porting an application
from a BSD platform onto a Linux box. When compiling, I have found that some of the header files call for `<bits/stl_alloc.h>`, which is missing from my computer. Does anyone have any idea as to where I can find this and/or why it is missing?

I am running a Fedora 12 machine with GCC4.4.4.

Comment: stl_alloc.h is not a standard C++ header file, and merely getting hold of it will almost certainly do you no good at all. Porting an application requires  a lot more than just having the same source code files present on the target platform.

Comment: You should not be including anything from bits sub directory. The standard only defines files in the main directory any sub directories used are an implementation detail.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify - I have a header file that is looking for this file.  Without this header file, I am receiving all sorts of undefined problems.  So my real question would be is there a Linux equivalent that does the same things as stl_alloc that I can implement instead?

Comment: You'll probably have to figure out what's going on and how to do it in Linux.  That's one of the problems you run into when porting.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message shows that a file from bits directory is missing.  To this could lead two possible ways:

1. You included this file explicitly from your application.  That's your fault then, since it's not a standard header, and it may not be in your standard include path. You should avoid doing this.  Most of the necessary mechanisms of interacting with the OS are in standard library (or in other ones specifically designed for portability), so you have better solutions than using bits of a particular STL implementation.
2. This file is included indirectly from some of the standard headers of STL.  The thing is that STL implementation on Fedora could be portable, and could have some BSD support.  It could have the following code in its headers:

   ```
   #ifdef __BSD__
   // BSD-specific include file
   #include <bits/stl_alloc.h>
   #elsif defined __LINUX__
   #include <bits/linux_alloc.h>
   #endif
   ```

   Normally, a program developed on Linux would include the correct file.  However, **your program might have defined BSD fingerprint on its own**, and this fingerprint could be misinterpreted by STL implementation as that it should include its BSD-specific parts.  And if you built it on BSD only, you owuldn't have noticed it at all.